# Why it works?(not overlapping) Pseudo-element of <main> with position: absolute and text with position: relative

Tags: html, css

I need to help to understand some css-code logic.

I have a  tag with absolute positioned pseoudo-element with red background.
The  tag has a nested  element with text.

In this case, pseudo-element overlapping  element. It's seems to be logical.

But if I add position: relative to  element, text will be visible!
And I can't understand this behaviuor. Why it works? Please explain me.

Example: https://codepen.io/testpro1/pen/eYbyEVx

```html
<main>
    <article>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</br>
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</br>
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</br>
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</br>
    </article>
</main>

<style>
    main::before {
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        content: "";
        background: red;
    }
    article {
      position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It is a z-index problem, which doesn't apply the same way depending on how the element is positionned. The text is there in the first version, it's just behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MDN has a good explanation on this, [Stacking without the z-index property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_without_z-index):

> When the z-index property is not specified on any element, elements are stacked in the following order (from bottom to top):
>
> 1. The background and borders of the root element.
> 2. Descendant non-positioned elements, in order of appearance in the HTML.
> 3. Descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance in the HTML.

Both the `::before` pseudo element and the `article` in your example, are descendants of `main`.

Any element with a `position` value *other* than the default `static`, is considered "positioned".

The `::before` *is* positioned, the `article` isn't - so the article gets put on the z-axis stack according to **2.** first, and the pseudo element according to **3.** after that. This explicitly overwrites the priority they would have gotten merely via their DOM order.

Now when you add `position: relative` to the article, that makes it a positioned element as well - and now **3.** applies for both of them, and they do get added on the z-axis stack in their DOM order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was helpful for me !